# Bash command to sum specific columns of numbers from a file with many columns

Tags: bash, addition

```
A  1  15  4
B  2  14  5
C  3  13  6
D  4  12  4
```

I would like to add columns 2 (1+2+3+4) and 3 (15+14+13+12) and eventually add them together, while ignoring columns 1 and 4. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sum columns 1, 3 and 1+3

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = " "} ; {sum+=$2} {sum2+=$3} END {print sum, sum2, sum+sum2}'  file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = " "} ; {sum+=$2} {sum1+=$3} END {print sum sum1}' file.txt
```